# is there any way to retrieve the csvSchema used by a cvsMapper when it's read from the first line of a file?

Tags: java, csv, jackson, fasterxml

I have a `CsvSchema` and `CsvMapper` set up to read `CSV` files with column names in the first line.

I need to be able to do some work on the data, alter specific fields, and then write the data back out while preserving the column order.
I'm presuming that the `CsvMapper` has an internal schema that it creates from the first line, since the map has all the correct `key-value` pairs.
So, is there any way to use the `writer` functions of `CsvMapper` that would use that schema to order the data for output?

```
CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
MappingIterator<Map<String, String>> it = this.mapper.readerFor(Map.class)
            .with(this.schema)
            .readValues(stream);
```

Right now, i'm getting a `CsvMappingException` for "Unrecognized column" on the first column of data, so it looks like it's not using the schema.

Comment: Which version of [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv) do you use? Your example should work. Could you show example `CSV` payload for which above code fails?

Comment: version 2.9.8. unfortunately, I can't post a payload, there's 100+ columns and i don't think seeing them would help much.  they're all plain text, no commas in the data. Nothing out of the ordinary. _This_ code works. it gets the input data, maps it just fine.  it's the writer that's failing. just as a stab in the dark I tried `this.mapper.writer().writeValueAsString(rows);` and got the exception on the first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build `SequenceWriter` using schema from first row you read from input file. `Jackson` uses [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) behind, so, order is kept. Assume your `CSV` input contains:

```
C1,name,type
I1,John,T1
I2,Adam,T2
```

You can read, update and write to console like on below example:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SequenceWriter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;

import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class CsvApp {

    private CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

    private void handle() throws Exception {
        File csvFile = new File("./resource/test.csv").getAbsoluteFile();

        CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader();
        MappingIterator<Map<String, String>> iterator = csvMapper.readerFor(Map.class).with(schema).readValues(csvFile);

        SequenceWriter writer = null;
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            final Map<String, String> row = iterator.next();
            if (writer == null) {
                writer = createWriter(row).writeValues(System.out);
            }

            // do something ...
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : row.entrySet()) {
                row.replace(item.getKey(), item.getValue() + "U");
            }

            // write back
            writer.write(row);
        }

        close(writer);
    }

    private ObjectWriter createWriter(Map<String, String> row) {
        CsvSchema.Builder writeSchema = new CsvSchema.Builder();
        writeSchema.setUseHeader(true);
        row.keySet().forEach(writeSchema::addColumn);

        return csvMapper.writerFor(Map.class).with(writeSchema.build());
    }

    private void close(Closeable closeable) throws IOException {
        if (closeable != null) {
            closeable.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new CsvApp().handle();
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
C1,name,type
I1U,JohnU,T1U
I2U,AdamU,T2U
```

See also:

1. [jackson-dataformats-text - Overview](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv)

Comment: to set up the writer, i have: `public void fill(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
        MappingIterator<Map<String, String>> it = this._mapper.readerFor(Map.class)
                .with(this._schema)
                .readValues(stream);
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            final Map<String, String> row = it.next();
            this.rows.add(row);
            this._writer = createWriter(row);
        }
        it.forEachRemaining(this.rows::add);
    }` how can I  get the output to a string, instead of system.out?

Comment: using a ByteArrayOutputStream and PrintStream to capture the output from the write, i've managed to get everything to work. thanks for all the help

Comment: @JustinWright, I'm glad to hear that! Because you are new user, please, take a look at: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)